# Testing the network bandwidth according to a port on a remote server

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I want to know how easily test the network bandwidth according to a port on a remote server?
Thanks regards!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need a traffic generator to generate the biggest amount of traffic on a certain port and monitor that port for a while, then divide the amount by the time to get an average. Be sure to take in to calculation the TCP-setup-latency.

This can be done by nutTCP for example or many other programs (jperf...).